# Writing data from excel to the text based file .dxf

Tags: dxf

First post on this forum and I'm new to VBA so I will be as detailed as I can.

I've made a macro that modifies dxf drawing templates inside an excel tab and then writes that data to a new dxf file. I'm currently writing the text file with the code below:

```
Dim Application2 As Variant

 Range("A:A").Copy
 Application2 = Shell("c:\windows\notepad.exe", vbMaximizedFocus)

 AppActivate Application2

 SendKeys "^(V)", True

 SendKeys "%fa", True
 SendKeys "%t", True
 SendKeys "{DOWN 2}", True
 SendKeys "%n", True
 SendKeys savetarget, True
 SendKeys "%s", True

 SendKeys "%fx", True
```

I've been trying to change to the method below so I don't need to open notepad and put in keystrokes.

```
FN = FreeFile
Open savetarget For Output Shared As #FN
For iCntr = 1 To copy_endline

mystring = workspace.Range("A" & iCntr).Value

Print #FN, mystring
mystring = ""
Next iCntr

Close #FN
```

This worked sometimes but it seems to modify the formatting somehow so the drawing becomes not readable to Autocad. If I manually copy the data from Row A and paste it into a notepad document it works fine.

Comment: Why don't you iterate the range and add each line into the DXF? It is hard to help you because you do not show us the content of the Excel file and thus what the resulting DXF file looks like.

Comment: The DXF is in a format that frankly doesn't make sense.   The Excel file uses a replace on variable names in the DXF file template. The DXF templates are stored as text in a tab of the Excel file.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the files. I'll try to look through the two files for the differences in formatting so I can provide some more info.

Comment: I couldn't find the difference. Does anyone know how the Print function changes the formatting of varying things like: tabbing, spaces, dates, etc.?

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't supply a output dxf file. Without a verifiable worked example no one can really assist you.

Comment: Understood. I will make an example dxf for this. I just didn't want to post my companies templates.

Comment: I just remebered to write back what fixed me issue. I found this post to help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729408/how-to-save-particular-column-data-of-an-excel-worksheet-to-txt-file-including#new-answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by using code from this post:
[How to save particular column data of an excel worksheet to .txt file including line breaks in each cell content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729408/how-to-save-particular-column-data-of-an-excel-worksheet-to-txt-file-including#new-answer)

I would thank them but I don't have enough reputation. haha

This while write a dxf file from data in one column in excel.

Mine looks something like this:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(SaveLocation & DWG_Name & ".dxf", True)
nLastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
nFirstRow = 1

For N = nFirstRow To nLastrow
    t = Cells(N, "A").Text
    a.WriteLine (t)
Next
a.Close
```